# SQL Server Update Field Max Value Subset of Data

Tags: sql, sql-update, max, dateadd

I'm trying to update a filed based on a subset of data within the table. If an assembly requires 3 components that have varying arrival dates, but can only be assembled once all three have arrived, how do I update the completed field? The Complete field would need to be the Max of the DateAdd between the like assembly, but I don't know how to define the WHERE statement to compare based on assembly.

Sample Data

```
SN      Assembly  Arrival       ProcessingDays
1000    A1        2017-07-03    2               
1001    A1        2017-06-02    2
1002    A1        2017-05-01    2
1003    A2        2017-12-15    2  
1004    A3        2017-07-03    2
1005    A3        2017-06-02    2
1006    A3        2017-05-01    2
```

Desired Output

```
SN      Assembly  Arrival       ProcessingDays  Complete
1000    A1        2017-07-03    2               2017-07-05
1001    A1        2017-06-02    2               2017-07-05
1002    A1        2017-05-01    2               2017-07-05
1003    A2        2017-12-15    2               2017-12-17
1004    A3        2017-09-03    2               2017-09-05
1005    A3        2017-08-02    2               2017-09-05
1006    A3        2017-07-01    2               2017-09-05
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you really want to update your table or just generate the `Complete` column, but the following CTE should be on the right track.  The trick baked into the cake with your question is that the number of processing days for the most recent record of each assembly also has to be identified, in addition to the max date.  For this, I use a two step CTE below.

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT SN, Assembly, Arrival, ProcessingDays,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Assembly ORDER BY Arrival DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT t1.SN, t1.Assembly, t1.Arrival, t1.ProcessingDays, t1.Complete,
        DATEADD(dd, t2.ProcessingDays, t2.Arrival) AS NewComplete
    FROM yourTable t1
    INNER JOIN cte1 t2
        ON t1.Assembly = t2.Assembly
    WHERE
        t2.rn = 1
)
```

CTEs are useful in so many ways, including making it easy to update a table using complex logic, but in an easy way.  Now we can update your `Complete` column as follows:

```
UPDATE cte2
SET Complete = NewComplete;
```

This is a blanket update, which is what your question seems to imply what you want, but you are free to add a `WHERE` clause to the above update if that makes sense.

Comment: I think it has to be an update command as these fields exist and will be constantly updated

Comment: Then let me update my answer.  I will assume that your table already has an empty `Complete` column.

Comment: Getting error, I've tried various combinations of semicolon and comma:  "Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 248
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon."

Comment: I don't see any problem with my code.  I assumed that your table is called `yourTable`, but that is about it.  Make sure you run everything together.  What I mean by this is that you should highlight everything from `WITH cte1 AS ...` until the update, and then run together.

Comment: I think the problem is that I invoke cte's earlier in the script so it's throwing it off, I've split it into smaller scripts and it seems to work. Thanks!